# It is not possible to cannot import name picamera

Tags: camera

I bought raspberry pi camera and it works, but when i use python to use the camera return Error: cannot import name picamera. I have install python3-picamera.and this is python programming:

```
from picamera import PiCamera
import time
camera = PiCamera() 
camera.start_preview()
time.sleep(10)
camera.capture('/home/pi/image.jpg')
camera.stop_preview()
```

Comment: please state what rpi do you use.

Comment: Did you follow this [Picamera installation](http://picamera.readthedocs.io/en/release-1.12/install.html)
?

Comment: are you running python 2 or 3?